# Changing URLs into HTML links

Tags: strings, ruby, url

This method changes all URLs in the string into an HTML link. The goal is to not mutate the string passed in, which I believe is a good practice.

The `new_string` code in this method does not seem idiomatic.

```
def autolink_string string
  return    if string.nil? 
  return '' if string.empty?

  regex = /(\S+\.(com|net|org|edu|gov)(\/\S+)?)/
  groups = string.scan regex
  matches = groups.map &:first
  new_string = string.clone

  matches.each do |match|
    new_string.gsub! match, "<a href='http://#{ match }'>#{ match }</a>"
  end

  new_string
end
```

How can I refactor to remove the `new_string`? Any other suggestions?

Comment: This method needs some polishing indeed, but are you aware that there are gems for this task? https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

Comment: Yes, I did some research. This is not a rails project, and from what I could guess rails_autolink is only for Rails. I didn't find any other useful gems. It turns out that the regex is simple anyway.

Comment: Ok. Let's see if somebody else answers (I am kind of hoarding the *ruby* tag lately ;-))

Comment: I don't know what kind of input you're dealing with, but here are some things to consider: What if the URL already includes "http:" (or something else)? What if there are "bad" chars after the domain, e.g. it's at the end of a sentence and followed by a period? What if the domain is a .co.uk, .io, or .museum or any one of the other [top-level domains](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)? What about chars that are illegal in URLs? What if the URL is uppercase? Robust URL detection is hard, but [here's a pretty good one](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls)

Comment: @Flambino - I have a helper method to handle the case that it already includes http://. I omitted it for clarity. It does not match the punctuation after the URL. I don't care about .co.uk, .io, etc. I don't care about illegal URL chars. It works for uppercase. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes:

- About the double `return` at the beginning: note that you could write `return string if !string || string.empty?`. In any case, I wouldn't check this, if the caller sends a `nil` as argument it's his/her fault. IMO in dynamic languages it does not make much sense to check the types of the arguments.
- Again, about the double `return` at the beginning: ok, let's say that you really need to do this check. As it may be seen as a guard, it *may* be ok to write a inline `return`. However, as a rule of thumb, it's better to write full indented conditional expressions, they are much more clear (at the meager cost of a couple of lines and an indentation level).
- `#{ match }` -> `#{match}`. Nobody puts those spaces.
- `regex = /(\S+\.(com|net|org|edu|gov)(\/\S+)?)/`: This looks like a brittle regular expression to detect URLs. Also are you sure you won't get a `http://` here? Anyway, you'll know what you need...
- `new_string.gsub!`: No need to do an in-place update. Use `String#gsub` with a block instead.

So I'd simply write:

```
def autolink_string(string)
  regexp = /(\S+\.(com|net|org|edu|gov)(\/\S+)?)/
  string.gsub(regexp) { |url| "<a href='http://#{url}'>#{url}</a>" }
end
```

Comment: OP should pick this answer, better than mine. `gsub` is the way to go, I used it before but failed due to something wrong.

Comment: that's very nice of you :-) but your answer also shows two of my points: it uses real conditionals and `gsub` with blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub!` and block directly with a clone.

```
def autolink_string str
  unless str.empty?
    regex = /(\S+\.(com|net|org|edu|gov)(\/\S+)?)/
    str.clone.gsub!(regex) do |match|
      "<a href='http://#{ match }'>#{ match }</a>"
    end || str # Return str if no match
  end
end
```

In console:

```
> str = "this is a test abc.com"
> result = autolink_string str
=> "this is a test <a href='http://abc.com'>abc.com</a>"
> str
=> "this is a test abc.com"
> result
=> "this is a test <a href='http://abc.com'>abc.com</a>"

> autolink_string "no url here"
=> "no url here"

> autolink_string ""
=> ""

> autolink_string "this is a test abc.com and test twitter.com"
=> "this is a test <a href='http://abc.com'>abc.com</a> and test <a href='http://twitter.com'>twitter.com</a>"
```

Comment: It seems that using `gsub` in the block is a good idea. However, I don't want to mutate the string.

Comment: @BSeven, then just clone it, no more lines needed. Results are same.

Comment: Works well, except that it returns nil if there are no matches: `autolink_string "no url here" => nil`

Comment: @BSeven, nice point! It depends on your usages, sometimes nil is preferred when you already have "str" in hand. If you choose to return something, I've revised the code to return `str` if no matches.